# Periodic Functions

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f:R \rightarrow R$ is continuous and periodic function .Prove that $f$ is bounded and uniform continous on R.

How can this be proven , it makes sense for me that it should be bounded but i don't have a clue how to prove that it's uniformly continous

Comment: If $P$ is the period, then note that $|f(x)-f(y)| = |f(x+iP)-f(y+jP)|$ for all $i,j$, so you can presume that $|x-y| <P$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: A continuous function on a *compact* set is uniformly continuous. The set $[0, \tau]$, where $\tau$ is a period of $f$, is compact.